# How to make a update form in angular?

Tags: angular

I want to create a update form which displays user details when component loads & then user can update with updated values also.
Also the form has image in it.

I tried to make one which has two fields i.e., (name & image) but I'm facing an issue as follows:

> when I update both the fields or when I just upload image it successfully works. But when I want to update name only it get me errors which says
>   **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

After debugging the code I actually realised that

> when I'm patching with the API response, image field is set with it's value like "http://localhost/angular/public/images/profile/1577338039_19-12-26_989779_image.jpg" (fake path) & when I only change name field & submit the image field doesn't have File type associated with it. Which gives me error maybe.

Here is a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6tf7d) for better understanding of what I code.

Comment: Your stackBlitz is not working

Comment: `AmenService` is missing in stackblitz

Comment: @Chenna yes it is just a service which gets data from API, response data which is coming I shared in a file called apiData.txt Please check

Answer (score 0):

After review your code in stackblitz it looks like you are setting value of **selectedImage** on change event in image selection.
It's obvious thing that whenever you are not selecting image then (change) event is not going to call.

And your variable **selectedImage** remains null.

That's why its throwing error like **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null**

So now you don't want to change image at update time then you have to check condition that it is null or not.If it is null then you can pass value of image as you are getting from API.

```
if(this.selectedImage!=null){
 formData.append('user_img', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
}
```

Comment: thanks mate.. I got the idea from your post. by checking selectedImage to be null & then append user_img. I actually only append name to formData which works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

By checking selectedImage to be null or undefined & then append name to formData as follows:

```
        if (this.selectedImage == null || this.selectedImage === 'undefined') {
            formData.append('name', this.updateForm.get('name').value);
        } else {
            formData.append('user_img', this.selectedImage, this.selectedImage.name);
            formData.append('name', this.updateForm.get('name').value);
        }
```